# How to build a graph for nodes with multiple edges in PyTorch geometric?

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

Suppose a node represents a bank account and an edge represents a transfer operation between two accounts. There may be multiple transfers between the two accounts. if this, how should I build a graph with pytorch geometric?

[image: 1]

I construct the graph as follows:

```py
x = [[0], [1]] # 0 for account A and 1 for account B
edge_index = [ [0, 0, 0],
               [1,1,1]
             ]
edge_attr = [[...], [...], [...]]  # some edge attr such as transfer time, transfer amount
 
Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index, edge_attr=edge_attr)
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that works. However it only makes sense when the dataypes for the individual edges are identical, which seems to be the case here, as you add a new edge for each transaction.